# Websocket Game - Sending data in bulk or in a constant stream

Tags: java, websocket, spring-websocket

I'm trying to develop a small web game using Spring Websockets. I am unsure of what the best method of sending game data updates to the client is.

Is it better to send all of the data in a bulk update at the end of each game update **or** is it better to send individual packets of data constantly as each object in the game is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I asked this question a week or 2 ago and got no response so I went ahead and created a test game and made 3 branches of the project to test this.*

**Short Answer**: Bulk updates are much faster when working with Spring Websockets.

The first branch I created was the "Packet Spread" branch. It sent data to the clients about each object in the game world as it looped through them and updated their attributes during a game tick.

The second branch I created was the "Packet Blob" branch. It collected all the data that was updated over a game tick and sent it in 1 bulk update at the end of the game tick.

I also created a third branch called "Packet Spread Threaded" which worked the same as the original Packet Spread branch except it passed all the game data to a separate thread before sending it.

I then tested each branch with 3 players on a benchmark that created and updated a massive amount of objects.

**Packet Spread** averaged about 40-70ms per game update.

**Packet Blob** averaged about 8-16ms per game update

**Packet Spread Threaded** averaged 20-40ms per game update.

I believe that there is a lot of overhead when sending data over a Spring Websocket so it ends up being more efficient to send large single packets instead of multiple small ones.